# std::sort is setting array pointer to null

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I'm trying to order a random generated array using the `std::sort` function as follows:

```
int *p = new int[n];

for (int i=0; i < n; ++i) {
    std::random_device r;

    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> uniform_dist(1, 6);
    p[i]= uniform_dist(e1);

}

// Prints array (ok)
for (int i=0; i < n; ++i)
{
    std::cout << p[i] << ' ';
}
std::cout << std::endl;

// P != NULL at this point
std::sort(&p, &p + n);
// P == NULL at this point
```

Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: Note that you are creating a new distribution every iteration of your loop. This essentially throws away the statistical distribution guaranties. You should create a single random engine, a single distribution object and pull multiple numbers from it.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki: But `p` isn't an array name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> std::sort(&p, &p + n);
> ```

This line causes undefined behaviour. `&p` is the address of the local `p` pointer object, *not* the location of the array where that object points to. `&p + n` then performs illegal pointer arithmetics with the address of the local object.

You should do it like this:

```
std::sort(p, p + n);
```

And of course, all of this is ultimately an exercise in futility, because you should just use `std::vector` anyway, and then it becomes:

```
std::sort(begin(v), end(v));
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I used `begin` and `end` instead of `std::begin` and `std::end` for a reason! :)

Comment: And what would that reason be exactly? [`begin()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`end()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) are in the `std` namespace, so why would you omit the `std::` prefix from them, but not from `std::vector` or `std::sort()`?  Be consistent with your example. Otherwise, I would just write it as `std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Because ADL causes them to be found even if the `std::` prefix is omitted, and `begin(v)` and `end(v)` are a more generic alternative and are encouraged by modern C++. I expect this style to be much more common in the next few years (just like `empty(v)` or `size(v)`).

Comment: ADL is a more advanced topic. For beginner who are new to C++ and/or STL, they should learn how to use `std::` before learning how and when it can then be omitted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I disagree. They should just learn good style first, then learn why it's good style.